# Which is faster: process data inside PHP or make several MySQL requests?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some extensive data to process: a very big table in MySQL. The processing takes place three times. Right now I am doing one request to MySQL and then in PHP I run a `while` loop three times to extract the necessary values.

Is what I'm currently doing the best option, or would it use less server resources to make three separate requests to MySQL with certain filters?

Comment: Please describe the algorithm you're using to process the data in more detail. Also could you clarify how big a "very big" table is?

Comment: You need to elaborate quite a bit for us to be able to give a proper answer. There are many factors that could change the aproach. One solution is often 'change database engine' when working with large datasets. The stuff I work with on a day to day is usually at a level you can forget using RDBMS. Describe the problem better and we can advice on tools and angle of attack.

Comment: Implement both. Measure both. Optimize both. Measure both again. Decide.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL as much as possible in this situation. It is potentially much quicker.

EDIT: As kindly pointed out below, it is not always better to use SQL queries over processing in PHP, and as such, the statement above may be misleading.

However, from the wording of this question I had assumed he was returning a large record set from the MySQL query and using several while loops to extract only certain values from the record set. If this assumption is true then I believe it would be quicker and less consumptive of resources to perform the whole operation within the MySQL query.

As this answer isn't very helpful to people finding this with similar problems it would be grand if the original poster could post some code to clarify the exact situation.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. If you're not using indexes properly say, it could be slower of course there are other factors too. But I'd say it's a bit of an ambitious sentence.

Comment: @James Yes it is, but I've taken some assumptions about what he is doing with the data from the wording of his question. It looks to me like he is only selecting certain values from the table, not processing the values beforehand. A MySQL Select statement, even a complicated one, is very likely to be much faster than using PHP (which probably uses loops and ifs quite a lot). Also, if these statements are used quite frequently then the indexing and caching that MySQL will do automatically will greatly increase the speed of the queries which will not happen AT ALL in just PHP

Comment: Sorry, but not true. There are many things MySQL is good at, but there are cases where you would want to do processing outside the db. It all depends on the problem domain. I have seen and worked on cases where even a higly tuned schema, queries and mysql-server spend more time running a query than 'transfer all rows over network' + 'process in code'.

Comment: Your recommendation completely ignores the issue of concurrency. If a complicated query is blocking updates to some tables issued by another server thread, the delay would be far more apparent to the end user.